# find the Jordan Form of the matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine  the  Jordan form of the matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\-1&-1&-1\\1&1&1\end {bmatrix}$

My attempts : i know  that  A is  idempotents  matrix that is $A^2 =A$,

Im not  able  to  find the  Jordan form

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: It is diagonalisable. and has rank one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1\\-1&-1&-1\\1&1&1\end {bmatrix}$

$S=\begin{bmatrix} -1&-1&1\\0&1&-1\\1&0&1\end {bmatrix}$

$J=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end {bmatrix}$

$S^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} -1&-1&0\\1&2&1\\1&1&1\end {bmatrix}$

Comment: thanks u @Noteinstein